# Ansible error executing pm2 startup command

Tags: ansible, pm2

When executing ansible playbook with command: `ansible-playbook 2_installJsReport.yml`

CentOS 7.6

Ansible 2.7.10

i get an error saying:

> TASK [make jsreport start at system restart] >*****************************************************************************>**************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["pm2", "startup"], >"delta": "0:00:00.601130", "end": "2019-04-24 12:59:33.091819", "msg": "non->zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-04-24 12:59:32.490689", "stderr": >"", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "[PM2] Init System found: systemd\n[PM2] To >setup the Startup Script, copy/paste the following command:\nsudo env >PATH=$PATH:/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin >/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 >startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username", "stdout_lines": ["[PM2] >Init System found: systemd", "[PM2] To setup the Startup Script, copy/paste >the following command:", "sudo env >PATH=$PATH:/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin >/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 >startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username"]}

Ansible script

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: make jsreport start at system restart
      command: pm2 startup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "error" message contains instructions you are supposed to follow to configure the startup:

> [PM2] Init System found: systemd
>   [PM2] To setup the Startup Script, copy/paste the following command:
>   sudo env PATH=$PATH:/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username

If you follow those instructions, it suggests that you should replace your task with something like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: make jsreport start at system restart
      become: true
      command: pm2 startup systemd -u username --hp /home/username
      environment:
        PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```